# How can I get header for node graphql resolver without express?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I know in express, we can have request.header, but without express, how can I get the header?

I'm working on an Apollo resolver, I'm trying to use header in my graphql resolver.

```
  async item (_, args, context) {
    if (ApiVersion === '2') {
      return await itemv2(args);
    }
    return await itemv1(args);
  },
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "without express". Are you running GraphQL Yoga? The standalone version of Apollo Server? Please provide additional details.

Comment: It is Apollo Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [shown in the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server/#constructoroptions-apolloserver), the `context` parameter passed to `ApolloServer`'s constructor can be either an object or a function. If it's a function, it should return the context object or a Promise that will resolve to one. The function is passed an object as its first parameter with a `req` property. This is an express [request](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req) object because that's what Apollo Server uses under the hood. You can access any properties normally available on this object, including the headers:

```
new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: ({ req }) => {
    console.log(req.headers.authorization)

    return req
  },
})
```

So if you use the whole `req` object as your context, you can do something like:

```
  async item (_, args, context) {
    if (context.headers['api-version'] === '2') {
      return await itemv2(args);
    }
    return await itemv1(args);
  },
```